# How to open new version of excel (I use both 2003 and 2010) in Powershell and import txt data into excel file?

Tags: excel, powershell

I use the code below to import txt file into excel. The problem is that I use 2 versions of Office (2003 and 2010).

The command $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
opens Excel 2003 I need to use Excel 2010 instead of 2003 and import new data.
My Excel 2010 is stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe

Only way I can open Excel 2010 in powershell is to call it with

```
Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"
```

but , rest of my code is ignoring Excel 2010. It will open and import data with Excel 2003 anyway.
Also change from

```
  $objExcel = New-Object -COMObject Excel.Application.11
```

to

```
  $objExcel = New-Object -COMObject Excel.Application.14
```

doesn't work.

Thank you for any help.

Steve

```
$CSVfile = "E:\test.txt"

#Create a new Excel object and add a new workbook.
#Delete the extra worksheets and rename the first worksheet.
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
 $Excel.visible = $true
$workbooks = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheets = $workbooks.worksheets
$worksheets.Item(3).delete()
$worksheets.Item(2).delete()
$worksheet = $worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Name = "Name of Worksheet"

#Define the connection string and where the data is supposed to go
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $CSVfile)
$CellRef = $worksheet.Range("A1")

#Build, use and remove the text file connector
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$CellRef)
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $True
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).Refresh()
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).delete()

$worksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```